# PUSH-уведомление дублируется с пустым содержимым

Tags: android, android-notification

Отправляется тестовый пуш в моё устройство.

Когда приложение активно, пуш приходит нормально и со звуком, когда приложение свёрнуто, приходят 2 пустых пуша и без звука. Даже если `onMessageReceived` оставить пустым, всё равно выводятся два пустых уведомления.

Класс принимающий PUSH:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService implements MyLocation, DownloadListner {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
   sendNotificationPushNewMessages();
}

private void sendNotificationPushNewMessages() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainInfoActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Hearty365")
            .setContentTitle("Default notification")
            .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
}
```

Текст PUSH

```
{"to":"cHj0nruQddQ:APA91bHZZ4i02rZA7s8qyEIWtBJE-5PUry-mhAUlUWE0z3XVa4kX4CTxwD9cwWLnp-FbAAwc9zBQMf9Hghwz5B7ym51NVSt_S-9ChHW09E2LfHQyT6mtCgjMkF1fNyvQIAKfguH63ze9","content_available":true,"priority":"high","data":{"type":"push_new_messages","text":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043a\u0430"}}
```

content_available и priority используются для ios версии

В чём может быть беда?
Может класс что-то недополучает, когда активити свёрнуто?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content available` и `priority` для ios версии в api была источником проблем для push-уведомлений.

Изначально я хотел использовать апи, как совмещённый с ios, поэтому добавил 2 строки для айфонов к имеющимся, но не думал, что все проблемы будут от этого, при активном экране у меня всё ж итак работало.. магия

Comment: можно подробнее , как вы решили эту проблему. в iOS 13 приходит пустой пуш. Но я не могу его даже отследить.